# Induction proof for digraph property

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I have a digraph described by $(V, E)$ with $n$ vertices such that $xy\in E$ or $yx\in E$ where $x,y$ are vertices. I want to prove by induction that

> The vertices of $V$ can be ordered as $v_1,...,v_n$ so that $v_i v_{i+1}\in E$ for all $i\in [n-1]$

I think I have my base case verified. At $n=1$ there's only one line mapping element $v_0$ to $v_1$, and that clearly can be ordered as $v_0, v_1$. And since $v_0 v_1 \in E$ and $i\in [0]$, the base case is verified. I think, I'm not to sure if I'm doing this step correctly.

Then I have the induction step, and this is where I don't know how to continue

Comment: Can you write out the induction step and try to push it as far as you can, to demonstrate where you're stuck? Induction does work out, and you just need to make an observation.

Comment: Is the not well formed expression xy V yx supposed to mean something?

Comment: @WilliamElliot it just means that E contains either xy or yx

Comment: It means nothing.  If you are going to use a formal lsnguage, then use it correctly.  Otherwise write it out with words.

Comment: Does $\vee$ not mean inclusive "or" ?

Comment: @Lex_i: William is correct but unhelpful. The point is that elements of $E$ must be edges of the digraph, and $xy\lor yx$ is not an edge. Alternatively, $\lor$ takes logical expressions as operands, not edges of graphs. What you’re trying to say, I think, is that $$\forall x\forall y\,(xy\in E\lor yx\in E)\,.$$ In other words, between any two distinct vertices there is an arc in at least one direction and possibly in both.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks, i'll edit it then